# Failure to stop ticking with Windows Form Timer in C#

Tags: c#, forms, timer

I've initialized a windows form timer in my constructor (and set it running at an appropriate time by writing "pTimer.Enabled=true".  In the constructor-

```
            pTimer = new Timer();
            pTimer.Enabled = false; 
            pTimer.Interval = timerSpeed;
            pTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(pTimer_Tick);
```

Inside the timer callback, I'm checking to see if my work has been completed.  Once it is, I'd like to stop the timer (in the sense that it won't keep calling the pTimer_Tick callback) and close a streamwriter that's doing the logging.

```
           private void pTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
                bool tempFinished = finished();
                log("finished() in timer tick = " + tempFinished.ToString());
                if (tempFinished)
                {
                     if (pTimer.Enabled == true)
                     {
                         log("We are going to stop the timer");
                         pTimer.Enabled = false;
                         Application.DoEvents();
                         log("We are going to close the streamwriter");
                         //myStreamWriter.Close();
                     }
                }
           }
```

The following behaviour seems to occur:

1. After the first time that finished()==true in the pTimer_Tick
   callback, we log "finished() in timer tick = True", and the code
   reaches pTimer.Enabled = false
2. Originally, I had not commented out closing the streamwriter and this was generating an error because it was continuing to attempt to write to code being logged from the pTimer_Tick callback
3. If we comment out myStreamWriter.Close(); (as written above), after 1. occurs, the code indeed seems to keep reentering the pTimer_Tick callback, it runs the finished() method when it reaches the "bool tempFinished=finished()" line, and the internal log to the finished() method indicates that it is going to output "true" again as expected, but the logging on the next line " log("finished() in timer tick = " + tempFinished.ToString());" is never down, and the next thing that appears in the log is the code accessing the finished() function again.

Does anyone have any suggestions about what could be wrong here?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: I don't think that `Application.DoEvents()` should be necessary.

Comment: Sorry!  I cannot see anything indicating that I can "accept" an answer.    Looking again.. - Do I enter something in "Answer your Question"? - Ok no, not there.  I can't see how to do this!!

Comment: I've tried playing with Start and Stop, but they have the same effect as enabled=true, false.  Yes, Application.DoEvents() looks to be unnecessary, I added it as a test to see if I could get the code to work.

Comment: @ashes999 `Timer.Stop` just sets `Enabled` to false...

Comment: @user1328382 There are no answers in this question, they're talking about your past questions...

Comment: @user1328382 look at your previous questions and click the outline of the checkmark on whatever answers answered your question.

Comment: @LarsTech in addition, I don't think `DoEvents` would help in the slightest...

Comment: @PeterRitchie I was just trying to be gentle.  :-)

Answer (score -1):

You are starting and stopping the timer by setting the `Enabled` property. Although you claim in the comments that this is sufficient, I'm not convinced.

Try using the `Start` and `Stop` timer functions instead.

Comment: I did try changing to start and stop a couple of days ago, but it didn't help.  Indeed, on the MS website it says "Calling the Start method is the same as setting Enabled to true. Likewise, calling the Stop method is the same as setting Enabled to false." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.stop.aspx)

Comment: Look at the source for `Start` and `Stop` in something like Reflector or look at the source at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx you'll see that `Stop` and `Start` just change the `Enabled` property.